What is topology on $\mathbb Z_3$?
Frankly, I have a hard time imagining what it is.
In his Cours d'arithmétique(1970), Jean-Pierre Serre defines $$\forall n\geq 1, A_n:=\mathbb Z/3^n\mathbb Z$$
Let us consider $A_1$. Serre's talking about "discrete topology on $A_1$", without even defining it. I've been looking: if I'm not mistaken, this is the topology defined by the set of parts of $A_1$ $$\tau_1:=\{ \emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\} \}$$
It is clear that $$\forall n\geq1(A_n,\tau_n) \text{ is separated space}$$ So, every $A_n $ is compact (finited unions of points) .
Then he writes :" If we give $\prod_{}^{}A_n$ the product topology , $Z_3$ has a topology that makes it a compact space (because it is closed in a compact space)."

I know that a closed space in a compact space is compact. The product topology $\tau$ is defined, I believe, by the set of sets of the form $$O_1\times O_2\times...\times O_m\times A_{m+1}\times A_{m+2\times...}$$
1.- Why $\prod_{}^{}A_n$ is compact ?
2.- Why $\mathbb Z_3$ is closed in $\prod_{}^{}A_n$ ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

For the first one, the keywords are Tychonoff theorem.


Serre's talking about "discrete topology on $A_1$", without even defining it.

Discrete topology on set $X$ is always given by full $\mathcal{P}(X)$, i.e. the collection of all subsets. Meaning every subset is open. This is a well known definition.

1.- Why $\prod_{}^{}A_n$ is compact ?

Because arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact. This is known as Tychonoff's theorem.

2.- Why $\mathbb Z_3$ is closed in $\prod_{}^{}A_n$ ?

$\mathbb{Z}_3$ in this context is defined as the inverse limit. Given quotient maps $\pi_{i,j}:\mathbb{Z}/3^j\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/3^i\mathbb{Z}$ for $i\leq j$ we define
$$\mathbb{Z}_3=\{(a_n)\in \prod A_n\ |\ a_i=\pi_{i,j}(a_j)\ |\ i\leq j\}$$
In general an inverse limit does not have to be closed in the product space. But it is always closed, if each $A_k$ space is Hausdorff, as you can see here: Is inverse limit topology closed in product topology? And in our case each space is discrete, and thus Hausdorff.

Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't have Tychonov's theorem in Dixmier's General Topology but I have it in Skandalis Topology and analysis,3rd year; p.290 all the same:( And the link to explain my question 2) is cool.

Tikhonov's theorem applies to families of general compact topological spaces, however complicated they may be. Here, these are very simple compact spaces. Wouldn't there be a way to prove the result without referring to Tychonov's theorem in this simple case?

Maybe, but I think the interesting case of Tychonoff's theorem is when the product is infinite, as it is here. (It is elementary that a finite product of compact spaces is compact.) The $A_n$ are trivially compact because finite, but their product is not.

Also note that an infinite product of discrete spaces is not discrete.

@StéphaneJaouen have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466504/countable-product-of-finite-topological-spaces-is-compact-without-tychonoffs-t


The link given by @freakish is perfect.
I found another answer that seems useful to me.
Let $\psi_n:\prod_k A_k\to A_{n-1} $ defined by $$\psi_n(x)=\varphi_n(x_n)-x_{n-1}$$
Then, $\mathbb Z_3=\cap_n\psi_n^{-1}(\{0\})$ is an intersection of closed subsets :$\psi_n^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed because it is the reciprocal image of a closed subset by a continuous function.

So, $\mathbb Z_3$ is closed.$\square$

Note that $$\boxed{\mathbb Z_3:=\varprojlim (A_n,\varphi_n)}$$ to know what $\varphi_n $ is(see also here.)
